# WordPress execute query

Tags: wordpress, execute

which method we are using for execute query in wordpress

Answer (score 2):

`wp_query()`: [**Manual page**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query)

Wordpress's API reference is the [**WordPress Codex.**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page)